# How to quickly calculate mode of a bunch of Decimal numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I am using `scipy.stats.mode` to calculate the mode of a list of numbers.  The mode gets calculated very quickly when the numbers are a bunch of `float`s (using the built-in `float`) but is much slower when the numbers are a bunch of `decimal.Decimal`s.  What's a fast (or faster) way to calculate the mode of a bunch of `Decimal`s?

Comment: Do you actually need all the features of `scipy.stats.mode`—returning multiple values if there are multiple modes, and returning the count of the mode along with the value? Or do you have an unambiguous mode and you want that value and don't care what the count is?

Comment: Because if it's the latter: You're not getting any speed benefit out of NumPy by storing Decimals, so switching to a non-NumPy function that's doing less work (and maybe using less storage) than `scipy.stats` might actually be faster. I could do some quick tests on the various options. But if they're not going to be usable to you, there's not much point.

Comment: @abarnert, I expect my mode to be unambiguous.  In fact, if my mode is ambiguous, then there's something either something unexpectedly wrong with my data or what I'm doing doesn't matter for that particular subset of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Decimal`s are inherently slower than `float`s, because all of the logic is implemented in Python with a bit of C acceleration, instead of in custom circuitry on your CPU.

Plus, if you've put them in a NumPy array, NumPy doesn't know anything about the `Decimal` type, so it has to store them as `drtype=object`, which means references to normal Python objects that have to be unboxed for every operation. By contrast, `float` values can be stored with `dtype=float`, which means they're just raw IEEE doubles that can be used directly (or even CPU-vectorized to process multiple values at a time).

So, I'd expect it to be about an order of magnitude or so slower. And when I run a quick test, it takes a bit over as long.

---

Second, [`scipy.stats.mode` is inherently slow if you have a lot of unique elements](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1432).

And, even if you don't, it's still doing extra work for extra features you may not need.

---

Anyway, you don't need to do any math to calculate the mode, just compare values for equality.

And we're not getting any benefit out of NumPy anywhere else.

So, simpler, less-powerful, non-NumPy solutions might actually be faster.

---

If you actually need any the features of `scipy.stats.mode`, that doesn't help you. For example, it can return multiple results if there are equally-common values; it gives the mode's count as well as the mode; it knows how to skip over NaN values instead of just telling you the mode is NaN; etc.

If you need any of the scipy features, you might want to consider building a `mode` replacement out of `find_repeats`, as described [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3035). This seems to be roughly 5x as fast as mode even in a fair case, and to not degenerate when there are tons of uniques. So, even adding the 10x cost for using Decimal, it still ends up pretty fast.

---

But if you don't need them?

- `statistics.mode(a)` is actually slightly faster than `scipy.stats.mode` even on the fair case even on an array of floats. And, instead of taking 10x as long if you give it `Decimal`s, it takes about the same amount of time.
- `collections.Counter(a).most_common(1)` is only about 50% slower than `statistics.mode`, and again doesn't slow down with `Decimal`s.

The point is, either of the obvious stdlib solutions outperforms `scipy` on `Decimal` values, by about 10x or 7x, on what seemed like a fair test. And if I craft a worst-case-for-`scipy` test where almost all of the values are unique, `scipy.stats.mode` becomes roughly 10x slower again, while the plain Python solutions don't slow down at all.

Anyway, for this case, the times are much more sensitive to details of the input data than for most. So, instead of posting benchmarks with a caveat that you really want to test against your actual data (knowing that half the readers aren't going to and are just going to take my benchmarks as meaningful), I'm going to keep my benchmarks to myself and insist that you really, really, really want to test against your own actual data.

Comment: I'm using `statistics.mode()` now, much faster!  I was running Python 2 so this necessitated a switch to Python 3.

Comment: @Joshua There is an [unofficial backport](https://pypi.org/project/statistics/) for 2.6+. But since you've already switched, just stick with 3.x.